# Common header with active class change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, header

Hi I have a set of webpages for my websites i tried to create a common header for all the three pages and added a click function but when i click on that link it takes me to that page but the active class function is not working. help me with this. thanks in advance.

Here is the common header.php

```
<ul id="navigation" class="nav navbar-nav" style="position:relative;">
    <li class="active op"><a href="/link1">link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/link2">link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/link3">link3</a></li>
    <li><a href="link4">link4</a></li>
</ul>
```

here is the jquery code i have added in header.php file

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#navbar li').on('click', function() {
        $('li.active').removeClass('active op');
        $(this).addClass('active op');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `$('#navbar li')` should be `$('#navigation li')`

Comment: you want to add `active` class after page redirection?

Comment: yes i want add active class for the page which i am in for example if i navigate to link2 form link1  the active class should be in link2 and the concerned page should open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code i had this same problem once. This will work fine

```
    $(function() {
     var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
     pgurl = "/vv/"+pgurl;
     $("#navigation li").each(function(){
         var link = $("a",this).attr('href');   
          if(link == pgurl){              
                $(this).addClass("active op");
          }
     })
});
```

Don't forget to add some libraries before it..